# Add title/Heading to JQxgrid Header

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqxgrid

I want to display heading in jqxgrid along with grouping so please tell how can i display it in the header or suggest me any link that explain the same

Answer (score 0):

To display a heading, you can use the jQuery Grid's Toolbar. To enable it, use the showtoolbar property and set it to true. Example: [toolbar.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/toolbar.htm?arctic)